# 401 with a POST using requests

Tags: python, json, python-requests

Using Postman, I can make a POST to an endpoint with a JSON body, and it returns be some results.

No authorisation on the endpoint.

Trying to get this to work with requests fails with a 401.
What am I missing here:

Code:

```
import json
import requests

url = 'https://wabi-australia-southeast-api.analysis.windows.net/public/reports/querydata?synchronous=true'
header = {"content-type": "application/json"}
body = {"version":"1.0.0","queries":[{"Query":{"Commands":[{"SemanticQueryDataShapeCommand":{"Query":{"Version":2,"From":[{"Name":"d1","Entity":"dimLGA","Type":0},{"Name":"l","Entity":"Linelist","Type":0}],"Select":[{"Column":{"Expression":{"SourceRef":{"Source":"d1"}},"Property":"LGAName"},"Name":"dimLGA.LGAName"},{"Measure":{"Expression":{"SourceRef":{"Source":"l"}},"Property":"Cases"},"Name":"Linelist.Cases"}],"Where":[{"Condition":{"Not":{"Expression":{"Comparison":{"ComparisonKind":0,"Left":{"Column":{"Expression":{"SourceRef":{"Source":"d1"}},"Property":"LGAName"}},"Right":{"Literal":{"Value":"null"}}}}}}},{"Condition":{"In":{"Expressions":[{"Column":{"Expression":{"SourceRef":{"Source":"l"}},"Property":"clin_status_n"}}],"Values":[[{"Literal":{"Value":"'Admitted to ICU'"}}],[{"Literal":{"Value":"'Admitted, not known to be in ICU'"}}],[{"Literal":{"Value":"'Home isolation'"}}],[{"Literal":{"Value":"'Hotel detention'"}}],[{"Literal":{"Value":"'Hospital in the home'"}}],[{"Literal":{"Value":"'Under investigation'"}}]]}}}]},"Binding":{"Primary":{"Groupings":[{"Projections":[0,1]}]},"DataReduction":{"DataVolume":3,"Primary":{"Window":{"Count":500}}},"Version":1}}}]},"CacheKey":"{\"Commands\":[{\"SemanticQueryDataShapeCommand\":{\"Query\":{\"Version\":2,\"From\":[{\"Name\":\"d1\",\"Entity\":\"dimLGA\",\"Type\":0},{\"Name\":\"l\",\"Entity\":\"Linelist\",\"Type\":0}],\"Select\":[{\"Column\":{\"Expression\":{\"SourceRef\":{\"Source\":\"d1\"}},\"Property\":\"LGAName\"},\"Name\":\"dimLGA.LGAName\"},{\"Measure\":{\"Expression\":{\"SourceRef\":{\"Source\":\"l\"}},\"Property\":\"Cases\"},\"Name\":\"Linelist.Cases\"}],\"Where\":[{\"Condition\":{\"Not\":{\"Expression\":{\"Comparison\":{\"ComparisonKind\":0,\"Left\":{\"Column\":{\"Expression\":{\"SourceRef\":{\"Source\":\"d1\"}},\"Property\":\"LGAName\"}},\"Right\":{\"Literal\":{\"Value\":\"null\"}}}}}}},{\"Condition\":{\"In\":{\"Expressions\":[{\"Column\":{\"Expression\":{\"SourceRef\":{\"Source\":\"l\"}},\"Property\":\"clin_status_n\"}}],\"Values\":[[{\"Literal\":{\"Value\":\"'Admitted to ICU'\"}}],[{\"Literal\":{\"Value\":\"'Admitted, not known to be in ICU'\"}}],[{\"Literal\":{\"Value\":\"'Home isolation'\"}}],[{\"Literal\":{\"Value\":\"'Hotel detention'\"}}],[{\"Literal\":{\"Value\":\"'Hospital in the home'\"}}],[{\"Literal\":{\"Value\":\"'Under investigation'\"}}]]}}}]},\"Binding\":{\"Primary\":{\"Groupings\":[{\"Projections\":[0,1]}]},\"DataReduction\":{\"DataVolume\":3,\"Primary\":{\"Window\":{\"Count\":500}}},\"Version\":1}}}]}","QueryId":"","ApplicationContext":{"DatasetId":"5b547437-24c9-4b22-92de-900b3b3f4785","Sources":[{"ReportId":"964ef513-8ff4-407c-8068-ade1e7f64ca5"}]}}],"cancelQueries":[],"modelId":1959902}

r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(body), headers=header)

print(r.status_code)
print(r.raise_for_status())
```

This returns a 401:

```
HTTPError: 401 Client Error: Unauthorized for url:
https://wabi-australia-southeast-api.analysis.windows.net/public/reports/querydata?synchronous=true
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: what authorization do you use in postman?

Comment: Note that in postman you send 8 headers while with requests you send only 1. What are the other 7 headers that you dont use with requests?

Comment: 401: “Similar to 403 Forbidden, but specifically for use when authentication is possible but has failed or not yet been provided”

Comment: Screenshots of auth and header info from postman
I tried a combo of different headers in my python script, and tried to match postman, but I am missing something key?

Comment: change `data=json.dumps(body)` to `data=body`

Answer (score 0):

Just found out Postman lets you generate a python code snippet for Requests.  Amazing.

This solved my problem.

```
import requests

url = "https://wabi-australia-southeast-api.analysis.windows.net/public/reports/querydata"

payload = "{\"version\":\"1.0.0\",\"queries\":[{\"Query\":{\"Commands\":[{\"SemanticQueryDataShapeCommand\":{\"Query\":{\"Version\":2,\"From\":[{\"Name\":\"d1\",\"Entity\":\"dimLGA\",\"Type\":0},{\"Name\":\"l\",\"Entity\":\"Linelist\",\"Type\":0}],\"Select\":[{\"Column\":{\"Expression\":{\"SourceRef\":{\"Source\":\"d1\"}},\"Property\":\"LGAName\"},\"Name\":\"dimLGA.LGAName\"},{\"Measure\":{\"Expression\":{\"SourceRef\":{\"Source\":\"l\"}},\"Property\":\"Cases\"},\"Name\":\"Linelist.Cases\"}],\"Where\":[{\"Condition\":{\"Not\":{\"Expression\":{\"Comparison\":{\"ComparisonKind\":0,\"Left\":{\"Column\":{\"Expression\":{\"SourceRef\":{\"Source\":\"d1\"}},\"Property\":\"LGAName\"}},\"Right\":{\"Literal\":{\"Value\":\"null\"}}}}}}},{\"Condition\":{\"In\":{\"Expressions\":[{\"Column\":{\"Expression\":{\"SourceRef\":{\"Source\":\"l\"}},\"Property\":\"clin_status_n\"}}],\"Values\":[[{\"Literal\":{\"Value\":\"'Admitted to ICU'\"}}],[{\"Literal\":{\"Value\":\"'Admitted, not known to be in ICU'\"}}],[{\"Literal\":{\"Value\":\"'Home isolation'\"}}],[{\"Literal\":{\"Value\":\"'Hotel detention'\"}}],[{\"Literal\":{\"Value\":\"'Hospital in the home'\"}}],[{\"Literal\":{\"Value\":\"'Under investigation'\"}}]]}}}]},\"Binding\":{\"Primary\":{\"Groupings\":[{\"Projections\":[0,1]}]},\"DataReduction\":{\"DataVolume\":3,\"Primary\":{\"Window\":{\"Count\":500}}},\"Version\":1}}}]},\"CacheKey\":\"{\\\"Commands\\\":[{\\\"SemanticQueryDataShapeCommand\\\":{\\\"Query\\\":{\\\"Version\\\":2,\\\"From\\\":[{\\\"Name\\\":\\\"d1\\\",\\\"Entity\\\":\\\"dimLGA\\\",\\\"Type\\\":0},{\\\"Name\\\":\\\"l\\\",\\\"Entity\\\":\\\"Linelist\\\",\\\"Type\\\":0}],\\\"Select\\\":[{\\\"Column\\\":{\\\"Expression\\\":{\\\"SourceRef\\\":{\\\"Source\\\":\\\"d1\\\"}},\\\"Property\\\":\\\"LGAName\\\"},\\\"Name\\\":\\\"dimLGA.LGAName\\\"},{\\\"Measure\\\":{\\\"Expression\\\":{\\\"SourceRef\\\":{\\\"Source\\\":\\\"l\\\"}},\\\"Property\\\":\\\"Cases\\\"},\\\"Name\\\":\\\"Linelist.Cases\\\"}],\\\"Where\\\":[{\\\"Condition\\\":{\\\"Not\\\":{\\\"Expression\\\":{\\\"Comparison\\\":{\\\"ComparisonKind\\\":0,\\\"Left\\\":{\\\"Column\\\":{\\\"Expression\\\":{\\\"SourceRef\\\":{\\\"Source\\\":\\\"d1\\\"}},\\\"Property\\\":\\\"LGAName\\\"}},\\\"Right\\\":{\\\"Literal\\\":{\\\"Value\\\":\\\"null\\\"}}}}}}},{\\\"Condition\\\":{\\\"In\\\":{\\\"Expressions\\\":[{\\\"Column\\\":{\\\"Expression\\\":{\\\"SourceRef\\\":{\\\"Source\\\":\\\"l\\\"}},\\\"Property\\\":\\\"clin_status_n\\\"}}],\\\"Values\\\":[[{\\\"Literal\\\":{\\\"Value\\\":\\\"'Admitted to ICU'\\\"}}],[{\\\"Literal\\\":{\\\"Value\\\":\\\"'Admitted, not known to be in ICU'\\\"}}],[{\\\"Literal\\\":{\\\"Value\\\":\\\"'Home isolation'\\\"}}],[{\\\"Literal\\\":{\\\"Value\\\":\\\"'Hotel detention'\\\"}}],[{\\\"Literal\\\":{\\\"Value\\\":\\\"'Hospital in the home'\\\"}}],[{\\\"Literal\\\":{\\\"Value\\\":\\\"'Under investigation'\\\"}}]]}}}]},\\\"Binding\\\":{\\\"Primary\\\":{\\\"Groupings\\\":[{\\\"Projections\\\":[0,1]}]},\\\"DataReduction\\\":{\\\"DataVolume\\\":3,\\\"Primary\\\":{\\\"Window\\\":{\\\"Count\\\":500}}},\\\"Version\\\":1}}}]}\",\"QueryId\":\"\",\"ApplicationContext\":{\"DatasetId\":\"5b547437-24c9-4b22-92de-900b3b3f4785\",\"Sources\":[{\"ReportId\":\"964ef513-8ff4-407c-8068-ade1e7f64ca5\"}]}}],\"cancelQueries\":[],\"modelId\":1959902}"
headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
}

response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data = payload)

print(response.text.encode('utf8'))
```